# How to use .format with variables in loop with QGIS/Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, qgis

I've got the following code, but I can't quite get it to work:

```
import glob
import os
import processing # for QGIS functionality

os.chdir("/home/mydir/vector")

columnid = ['SAMP300','SAMP100','SAMP30', 'SAMP10']

for x in glob.glob("prefix*.shp"):
    for y in columnid:
        for z in [1, 2, 3]:
            output_alg0='"/home/mydir/vector/samples/{x}_{y}_{z}.shp"'.format(x=x.rstrip('.shp'), y=y, z=z)
            output_0='processing.runalg("qgis:randompointsinsidepolygonsvariable","/home/mydir/vector/{x}",0,"{y}",1000,output_alg0)'.format(x=x, y=y)
```

The script reads through a directory of `.shp` files, and uses variables to name the outputs. `output_alg0` creates the output file name used in the next step. The file name is based on the original file, and two variables within the loop. `output_0` is the actual QGIS algorithm that is run, which references each `.shp` file in the loop, passes the `columnid` variable and some fixed parameters, and references `output_alg0` for naming the output `.shp` file.

If I append `print` in front of the two commands within the loop, I get the output that I'm expecting (i.e., the {x},{y}, and {z} variables are correctly populated. Furthermore, the script gives no error when executed, but no output is produced.

Here's an example of the output by appending `print` and parentheses to the two lines within the loop:

```
output_alg0="/home/mydir/vector/samples/prefix_SAMP10_3.shp"
output_0=processing.runalg("qgis:randompointsinsidepolygonsvariable","/home/mydir/vector/prefix.shp",0,"SAMP10",1000,output_alg0)
```

I can copy and paste both lines exactly as they appear above into the QGIS Python Console and the commands are executed as expected (i.e., random point file is generated based on the input shapefile, and an output shapefile is created as specified).

I think it has something to do with how I'm using `.format` and/or perhaps how I'm using single and/or double quotations, and/or some sort of Python/QGIS interaction that I don't quite understand.

**EDIT**: Instead of using the two `output_` prefixes, I also tried out this one-liner version, and the script executes (without error), but no output is created.

```
import glob
import os
import processing # for QGIS functionality

os.chdir("/home/mydir/vector")

columnid = ['SAMP300','SAMP100','SAMP30', 'SAMP10']

for x in glob.glob("prefix*.shp"):
    for y in columnid:
        for z in [1, 2, 3]:
           'processing.runalg("qgis:randompointsinsidepolygonsvariable","/home/mydir/vector/{w}",0,"{y}",1000,"/home/mydir/vectorsamples/{x}_{y}_{z}.shp")'.format(w=x, x=x.rstrip('.shp'), y=y, z=z)
```

Comment: What is your EXPECTED output?

Comment: You script doesn't output anything. You could add prints for those two variables in the scope of the for loop to see the values assigned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed my **EDIT**-ed line written as:

```
'processing.runalg("qgis:randompointsinsidepolygonsvariable","/home/mydir/vector/{w}",0,"{y}",1000,"/home/mydir/vectorsamples/{x}_{y}_{z}.shp")'.format(w=x, x=x.rstrip('.shp'), y=y, z=z)
```

to this, which wraps `exec` with quotations marks around the line above:

```
exec('processing.runalg("qgis:randompointsinsidepolygonsvariable","/home/mydir/vector/{w}",0,"{y}",1000,"/home/mydir/vectorsamples/{x}_{y}_{z}.shp")'.format(w=x, x=x.rstrip('.shp'), y=y, z=z))
```

The above modification to the script is running and iterates through the list of `.shp` files within the specified directory; however, I don't think this is the most kosher answer possible. I'll hold off accepting my own answer if something better and/or more QGIS-friendly comes along.

PS-thanks to @Adam Smith for pointing out `exec`

Answer (score 0):

Currently your loop is generating the variables how you want them to and assigning them to `output_alg0` and `output_0` the way you want, but you don't ever DO anything with them after that.

I've asked for your expected output in a comment. If you add that we can probably figure out how to get you there. My GUESS is that you're trying to execute `output_0` (which currently is just a string that looks like a python command). In which case you'd have to use `exec(output_0)` but be wary of using `exec` in general. It's a scary command.

**EDIT:**

If I were you, I'd do something more like:

```
# inside your loops::
output_alg0='"/home/mydir/vector/samples/{x}_{y}_{z}.shp"'.format(x=x.rstrip('.shp'), y=y, z=z)
output_0 = processing.runalg("qgis:randompointsinsidepolygonsvariable", "/home/mydir/vector/{x}".format(x=x), 0, y, 1000, output_alg0)
```

That way you're running the script directly rather than writing a bit of code then executing it.

Comment: OK, I've added the expected output. Both lines, when pasted directly into the QGIS Python Console, work as expected. I'll try out the `exec(output_0)` option if I'm left with no option to avoid blowing things up :)

Comment: `exec(output_0)` didn't work. I've tried removing `output_0=` and running the script, but that doesn't work either.

Comment: @prophet60091 You're wrapping the whole thing up as a string. Why not just call it and format the individual arguments?

Comment: unfortunately, your edit didn't work. I'm now wondering if this is a QGIS/Python issue? I've double-checked the outputs from the code in my answer, and everything has output as expected. I'll continue to hold out for a "proper" QGIS/Python answer.

Comment: @prophet60091 I still don't know what you're expecting to happen, but since the exec solution does exactly what this one does, that's not it